# What definitions can I refer to the meaning 'complementizer'?

Tags: conjunctions

Sentences:

> Sound of **her** voice
>
> Crumbs of **its** bread

Question:

> 1) What definitions can I refer to the meaning 'complementizer'?
>
> 2) Can I refer words as **'her', 'its'** to the meaning 'complementizer'

Additional information:

> I know for sure that it can be 'that' word *(like in its sentence)* but I found nothing [more](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complementizer)

Comment: Traditional grammar defines a complementizer as a word that marks a subordinate clause as functioning as a complement to another word. We don't use the term nowadays; instead we simply have a word category (part of speech) called "subordinator" which consists of "that", "for", "to", "whether" and "if", all of which can introduce complement clauses. "Her" and "its" are genitive pronouns, a completely different word category; they typically function as determiners.

Comment: @BillJ *Complementizer* isn't a term in 'traditional' grammar; it seems to have arisen in TFG circles in the 1960s.

Comment: The Oxford Dictionary has it listed with the same def as mine. It's a useless term that does no work as far as I can see. Two of my dry-as-dust grammars use the term as well. Maybe you should ask the OP why or where they hit upon the term.

Comment: @BillJ *Complementizer* and *subordinator* seem to be mostly the same thing, except that the folks who use *complementizer* tend to include things like relatives and ACC/POSS *-ing*s in the term. [Here](https://books.google.com/books?id=86v3bjkjYskC&pg=PA95&lpg=PA95&dq=subordinator+complementizer&source=bl&ots=kiS0ROOHYO&sig=R2Aa8xeW28HEQIoOUe2CcRnBOuk&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjFvMnsipjTAhWR14MKHeg2CK4Q6AEILTAD#v=onepage&q=subordinator%20complementizer&f=false)'s a fairly contemporary (2010) discussion, which makes it "clear" that the terminology is middling murky.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1. What definitions can I refer to the meaning 'complementizer'?**

There's little agreement among grammarians on how to categorize the core 'function' words in English; but the term *complementizer* is generally used only for words which introduce clauses. According to the [SIL Glossary of Linguistic Terms](http://www-01.sil.org/linguistics/GlossaryOfLinguisticTerms/WhatIsAComplementizer.htm)

> A complementizer is a conjunction which marks a complement clause.

And the [Lexicon of Linguistics](http://www2.let.uu.nl/uil-ots/lexicon/) at the Utrecht Institute of Linguistics defines *complementizer* as an

> element introducing a subordinate clause

*CGEL*<sup>†</sup> doesn't use *complementizer* at all, but it does use *subordinator* in a very similar sense. It recognizes only five subordinators: *that, for, to, whether, if*. You should note, however, that *CGEL* regards *to* as a subordinator of VPs, not clauses, and that *CGEL* categorizes most of what traditional and many contemporary grammars call *subordinating conjunctions* as *prepositions*.

- *(skip this unless you're really fascinated by grammatical theory:*)
  There is very little consensus among contemporary grammarians on the terminology for the 'function' words. Many of these words in fact serve multiple syntactical functions not only across utterances but even in individual instances. Consider, for instance, this sentence:

  > I haven't yet decided which theory I will follow.

  Here *which* acts as (a) a determiner on *theory*, (b) an 'interrogative' in the sense that it points to a gap, a blank to be filled in, (c) a 'subordinator' in the sense that it marks the following clause as subordinate, and (d) yes, a 'complementizer' in the sense that it marks the following clause as a complement of the verb *decide*.

  And I can readily imagine a grammarian generalizing the SIL definition to include words which mark entities other than clauses as complements. For instance, an *of* PP following a noun derived from a transitive verb usually marks its object as a complement of the noun rather than a modifier—the 'direct object' of the noun—

  > *the conquest **of** Granada* means "the act or fact of conquering Granada"

  So in this case the preposition *of* could be said to act as a 'complementizer'. ... That's sort of far-fetched; but it points up the fact that in the end, *complementizer* (or any other grammatical term) means whatever its user's particular approach to syntactic analysis needs it to mean.

**2. Can I refer words like 'her', 'its' to the meaning 'complementizer'?**

No. In your examples *her* and *its* are not complementizers but possessive pronouns acting syntactically as *determiners*—which is another multivalent term about which scores of articles and many entire books have been written.

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>Huddleston and Pullum, *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*, 2002</sub>

Comment: You'd know better than me, but I have the feeling ***determiner*** is still a genuinely useful term when analysing words in terms of their function within utterances, even if the precise definition gets hazy around the edges. I'm not sure ***complementiser*** fills a useful role in such contexts (practically every definition just cites ***that*** as an example, in contexts where it can often be discarded anyway).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I agree that *determiner* is useful--it's just pinning down what it is and how it works is complicated. *Complementizer* is ugly, and seems to be little used these days; but in its heyday it referred to a lot more than *CGEL*'s canonical five, including relatives and Acc/Poss+*ing*, and seems to have had considerable currency in discussion of languages other than English.

Answer (score 2):

**Definition of Complementizer**
In English Grammar, a Complementizer is a word used to introduce complement clause.
A complementizer is a conjunction which marks a complement clause.
A complementizer is a type of word category that turn the clause into the subject or object of a sentence.

Complementizers include subordinate conjunctions, relative pronouns, and relative adverbs.
Example: I wonder if she will come.
If is a complementizer in the above sentence.
Complement types often have associated with them a word, particle or affix whose function is to identify the entity as a complement. Such form are known as complementizer.

In English:

- That is a complementizer associated with a complement type named after it: that clause.
- If is a complementizer
- To is a complementizer
- While, since, because, so that, such, before, after, until... are complementizers.
- Who, whom, whose, what, which, why, when, where and how are also complementizers.

Sound of **her** voice  (her is not a complementizer according to the explanation above)

Crumbs of **its** bread (also its is not a complementizer)

References:
[Thoughtco.](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-complementizer-1689770)

Comment: In most modern grammars that use the term *complementiser*, words like *because*, *before* and so forth are prepositions, not complementisers, I believe.